# How to mock whether information is sent to another server correctly?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I need to mock test this case:

I have completed a feature in my server(called server1), so that
when server1 receives a request with conditionA, it sends metrics information “conditionA:1” to another server2 (the role of server2 is to collect result of all metrics. e.g. if server2 receives “conditionA:1” twice, it will record: “conditionA: 2").

How to unit test my feature using mock so that I know the information is received by server2?

Note I know how to create a mock request which results in conditionA. But I do not know how to unit test whether the metric IS sent to server2 correctly. Any idea?

Comment: I am working on application layer so do not know how they communicate. must be must be some protocol similar to http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using EasyMock (among others).

Suppose you have a function in a concrete class called "sendMetrics()". That function's job is to take metrics as a parameter and send them to server2.

To mock this, you would create an interface that defines the sendMetrics() function, have your aforementioned concrete class implement the interface, and then use EasyMock to create a Mock implementation of the interface.

Then, in your testing, you tell EasyMock to expect a call to sendMetrics(), and, when the call is made, return a "success" value of your definition.

**EDIT**
Your question specifically says "I need to mock test this case", and it says "How to unit test my feature...". So, I assumed you were talking about a Unit test. Based on your comment however (as well as "...so that I know the information is received by server2") makes it sound like you want to perform an integration test.

Remember, there's a difference between Unit tests and Integration Tests. I described a Unit Test with Mocking. The Mock is basically like saying "Ok Unit test, let's assume that Server2 is working correctly, such that if you call it, it returns a happy result". Presumably you would want to Unit test Server2 as well, perhaps with Mocks as well ("Ok Server2, let's assume that Server1 sent logical data..."). You can also use Mocks for negative testing, which I'll leave up to you to figure out. Verifying a "real case" sounds like an Integration test though (i.e. Server1 actually connects to server2).

Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks Cody. I do not understand how your test can verify in real case, calling sendMetric() from server1 will create a correct information to server2? in your solution, mock will return "success" in any case.

Comment: I responded above in the "EDIT" section

Comment: Hi, Cody: I meant unit test. I want to verify the information generated by server1 is correct. for example: suppose it has received a req. with conditionA, it will send ("conditionA:1") instead of ("conditionB:1"). I think I realized the diff btw. intergrate and unit test now. Thx. I would do this: 1), generate an expected_report="conditionA:1"; 2) define a actual_report which is empty at beginning; 3) define a mock so that if a function foo(actual_report) is called,then return conditionA; 3) call foo(actual_report); assert (actual_report is the same as expected_report)

Comment: Yep, that looks about right. If you found my assistance helpful, an upvote and/or a green checkmark would be greatly appreciated :)